# Disable button if margin-left = -3200

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to figure out how to disable a button if `margin-left` on an element is equals to `-3200` pixels. Ive the following that seems to run my function on page load, can anybody see where I'm going wrong?

```
if ($('.hero-carousel')offset().left = -3200) {
    alert('test');
}
```

Comment: First port of call when something doesn't work as you expect should ***always*** be the console. Also note that `margin-left` will return a different value to `offset().left` - which is it you want?

Comment: if ($('.hero-carousel')offset().left = '-3200px') {

Comment: I want margin-left @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 4):

You missed `dot` before offset() and need to use =`=` instead of `=` for `equality` comparison.

```
if($('.hero-carousel').offset().left == -3200) {
    alert('test');    
}
```

Edit

For getting margin left you need to use css function instead of offset()

```
if($(".hero-carousel").css("margin-left") == -3200 + "px") {
    alert('test');    
}
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to work @Adil, is that because I'm using margin-left as opposed to left

Comment: @Adil don't forget getting `css('margin-left')` will give you `-3200px`

Comment: No luck @RoryMcCrossan, when the page loads, the margin left is 0. on click it moves left, could this be part of the problem?

Comment: I could not understand what exactly you are try to achieve as you are incrementing margin-left by 1280 on button click and on click of div you are looking for negative margin-left. Check updated demo, first click on button to set margin-left 1280 and later click div to compare the margin-left with 1280 px, http://jsfiddle.net/BXu2f/2/