# Disable button when element on web page margin becomes minus X pixels jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable button if margin-left = -3200](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955652/disable-button-if-margin-left-3200)

I have a page that when it loads, there is a div that is margin-left:0px; on the click of a button, this element moves left in 600 pixel increments. Somehow I want to try and listen to when the element is -3200 pixels from the left only I cant seem to figure it out.

Can anybody see where im going wrong?

```
$(".hero-carousel").on("click", function(event){
    if($(this).css("margin-left") == -4480) {
        alert('test');    
    } else {};
});
```

Comment: isn't this the same question as your last one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955652/disable-button-if-margin-left-3200

Comment: Don't you know how to debug with browser tools?
This is a quite simple issue to discover what returns
`$(this).css("margin-left");`
If not try at least `console.log($(this).css("margin-left"));` and open your browser console to see it

Comment: You mention "-3200 pixels" in your description, but your code has "-4480px"...

Comment: @Liam - [**Check this jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fjDTt/1/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this...

```
$(".hero-carousel").on("click", function(event){
        var left = parseInt($(this).css("margin-left"), 10);
        if (left <= -3200) {
            //  do something here
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: No luck, Ive tried an alert if left but  nothing...

Comment: @Liam Are you using the debugger and `console.log()` to try and identify the problem?

Answer (score 1):

In your case `.css("margin-left")` probably returns srting like **-4480px**
and you're compareing it to an integer. So get rid of the px in the end and parse it to a number

Actually as @lan said bellow the `parseInt()` would strip out the 'px' for you and turn it into integer

Comment: That shouldn't matter; JavaScript will implicitly convert the string to a number for comparisons.

Comment: Not in that case, because there's probably 'px' in the string

Comment: @kidwon You might want to mention that then (the real reason why the comparison wouldn't work)

Comment: And also include the "solution" of just using `if(parseInt($(this).css("margin-left"), 10) == -4480) {` - the `parseInt` will strip out the "px"

Comment: No need to get rid of the "px", just use `parseInt`